# Am I specifying a 3 level model correctly with lme4?

Tags: lme4-nlme

I am new to lme4 and curious if I am specifying my model correctly.

I have EMA data that was collected within 3 bursts (baseline, mid-intervention and post-intervention). Within each burst, participants completed 3 EMA surveys a day for 7 days.

Participants were also randomized to an intervention vs. a control group. I am interested to see if the interaction between burst*arm influences the relationship between stress and mindfulness. Importantly, individuals completed multiple bursts. What I have here is moment as level 1, burst as level 2 and individual as level 3. I am looking for a random intercept and random slope effect.

Started by disaggregating my within and between-level effects.

```r
data1 <- bmlm::isolate(data, by = "base_Id",
                       value = c("MAAS_avg", "scs_avg", "ders_avg", 
                       "stressfulevent", "severity"),
                            which = "both")
```

then I ran the model ...

```r
model1 <- lmer(MAAS_avg ~ 1+ tressfulevent_cb + stressfulevent_cw + 
               burst + arm + burst * arm +
                (1 + stressfulevent_cw | base_Id) + (1 | burst),
              REML = TRUE,
              data = data1)
```

This ran, but I am not entirely sure if it is correct. Thoughts?